# Assign command keyboard shortcut from popup or options

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible with the Chrome API to let users assign a keyboard shortcut from within the extension popup or options page? Without them having to go to extensions page, scroll to the bottom and open keyboard shortcut menu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Chrome there's no method to assign a shortcut key programmatically, but you can add a button or a link in the extension popup that will open the built-in dialog.

popup.html:

```html
<button id="hotkey">Assign a shortcut key</button>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
```

popup.js:

```js
document.getElementById('hotkey').onclick = () => chrome.tabs.create({
  url: 'chrome://extensions/configureCommands'
});
```

Notes:

- chrome:// URLs can be opened only via chrome/WebExtensions API methods,
  but not via `<a href="...">` links directly.

  You can still use a standard `<a>` link with a click listener shown above; just don't forget to prevent the default click event to avoid an error in the console:

  ```js
  document.getElementById('hotkey').onclick = event => {
    chrome.tabs.create({url: 'chrome://extensions/configureCommands'});
    event.preventDefault();
  };
  ```
- In Opera browser the URL is `opera://settings/configureCommands`
  You can detect the browser using `navigator.userAgent` string
- In Firefox there's currently no way to open this UI programmatically so you'll have to show an instruction to open `about:addons` page, click the gear icon, then choose "Manage extension shortcuts". However, Firefox allows setting the hotkeys programmatically using [browser.commands.update](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/commands/update).

Comment: Out of interest, where did you dig out `chrome://extensions/configureCommands` URL?

Comment: It was added a few months ago in [Stylus](https://github.com/openstyles/stylus), the new fork of the old Stylish extension.

Comment: Oh, it _is_ actually in the docs at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands#usage _"The user can manually add more shortcuts from the chrome://extensions/configureCommands dialog."_

Comment: That chrome://extensions/configureCommands link no longer seems to work...

Comment: It certainly works for me. The final URL is different though, Chrome redirects it to chrome://extensions/shortcuts

Comment: They re-added the `chrome://extensions/configureCommands` redirect in [Chromium bug 775698](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=775698). From the "[MD Extensions]" tag in the commit message it seems like this was part of the move to the [Material Design-based Extensions page](https://ww.9to5google.com/2017/03/08/latest-dev-build-of-google-chrome-includes-a-material-design-extensions-page/). I'm not sure which version of Chrome started supporting the `chrome://extensions/shortcuts` URL, and the docs (as @Xan mentioned) still state `chrome://extensions/configureCommands`.

Comment: works for me, only that I change the url to the "shortcuts," still works~